# Using Code-Snippets in Discussion

Tags: discussion, support

I'm currently in the process of writing up an answer for another Arqader, in the field of Minecraft, which either requires the **use of a lot of images** or **heavy emphasis through massive code blocks**.

The question: [How do I handle 'Arena-Only' Equipment?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/300052/how-to-handle-arena-equipment-in-1-7-10-so-it-cant-be-taken-away-by-players?noredirect=1#comment424698_300052)
If you've seen my answer to the above, you'll infer that I am considering the use of Code Blocks in a gaming site - not Stack Overflow.
I know that this is slightly unethical in a way, but is this a practice worth using?

To iterate again, my answer would consist of **Lots of Programming** or **Images of a Redstone Machine**. Please leave your comments, I am a tad stuck here.

Comment: [See here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7437/1351) for general guidelines for the use of code blocks and code ticks (inline code), but suffice it to say if your solution is code-like, and command block commands or plugin scripts are both code-like, then by all means use code blocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Ok**. This is fine. Games these days increasingly include programming elements. There's no problem in using code blocks to include commands or even [entire programs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/249733/20306) in your answer. The code block feature exists on all SE sites, and should be used for code-like things.